# Getting inconsistent results for border-bottom-color with Playwright

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I'm new to Playwright and trying to verify that, on hover, the `border-bottom-color` is set to a specific rba value.

This is the element style that is applied on hover as seen in the browser dev tools:
[image: Browser dev tools showing border-color-bottom].

However, when I run the test I keep getting different values.

[image: Browser dev tools showing incorrect border-color-bottom]

```ts
test('primary-nav-gets-hover-state', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://example.com/');
  const caseStudiesLocator: Locator = page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Case Studies' }).first();

  const caseStudiesElem = await caseStudiesLocator.elementHandle();
  expect(caseStudiesElem).not.toBeNull();
  
  const div = await caseStudiesElem!.$('.nav-link-text');
  expect(div).not.toBeNull();

  await caseStudiesLocator.hover().then(async () => {
    const borderColor = await div!.evaluate((el) => {
      const style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
      return style.getPropertyValue('border-bottom-color');
    });

    expect(borderColor).toBe('rgb(224, 25, 50)');
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="/case-studies">
    <div class="nav-link-text" style="border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Case Studies</div>
</a>
```

[image: Screenshot of the link that is being tested]

Comment: Maybe give it a little more time for the change to be applied?

Comment: Best not to mix `await` and `then`. Have you considered `waitForFunction` to poll until the change occurs? Timeouts are race conditions that can generate false negatives or slow down tests.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was that Playwright wasn't waiting for the transition to complete. I'm not sure if this is the appropriate thing to do but I added

`await page.WaitForTimeout(1000);`

and I'm not consistently getting a passing test.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to waiting for a timeout, I found [this answer](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/15660#issuecomment-1184911658) on Github.
My final code wound up being the following:

```ts
test('primary-nav-gets-hover-state', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://example.com/');
  const caseStudiesLocator: Locator = page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Case Studies' }).first();

  await caseStudiesLocator.hover();
  await waitForAnimationEnd(caseStudiesLocator);

  const div: Locator = caseStudiesLocator.locator("div");

  const borderColor = await div.evaluate((el) => {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    return style.getPropertyValue("border-bottom-color");
  });

  expect(borderColor).toBe("rgb(224, 25, 50)");
  });
});
```